# Entity with @EmbeddedId , @GeneratedValue and @ManyToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, composite-key

I worked with postgres database, I have a `Conventionnement` entity with `ManyToOne` relationship with convention and organization, I want to  create 3 primary keys `convention_id`, `organization_id` and the `GeneratedValue id`, i used @Embeddable like the below example, but I had the below error

> Caused by: org.hibernate.annotations.common.AssertionFailure:
>   Declaring class is not found in the inheritance state hierarchy:
>   ConventionnementIdentity

and when I moved the id in Conventionnement class i had this error

> ConventionnementIdentity must not have @Id properties when used as an
>   @EmbeddedId

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "conventionnement")
public class Conventionnement implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private ConventionnementIdentity conventionnementIdentity;

    @MapsId("convention_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Convention convention;

    @MapsId("organization_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Organization organization;

    //getter and setter
}

@Embeddable
public class ConventionnementIdentity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "convention_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long conventionId;

    @Column(name = "organization_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long organizationId;

    //getter and setter
}
```

Comment: why are you using  @Id inside `Embeddable`. Remove it and then try

Answer (score 3):

You have defined an `@EmbeddedId`, but inside it you declare another `@Id`, thus the error. Make the generated id point to the correct id column in your table (below I've assumed "id" as column name):

```
@Embeddable
public class ConventionnementIdentity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator", sequenceName="YOUR_DB_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "convention_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long conventionId;

    @Column(name = "organization_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long organizationId;

    //getter and setter
}
```

Comment: when i added a new convention from a rest client, it shows me this error: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class com.back.domain.Conventionnement

Comment: I thought you omitted the db sequence name, I've edited my answer. Create db side a sequence (YOUR_DB_SEQ in my example) to take care of the progressive id.

Comment: always the same problem (null id generated for:class com.back.domain.Conventionnement; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class com.back.domain.Conventionnement), here is the project in github so that you have more information about the code [link](https://github.com/akanzari/convention)